# MySQL - populate table field with value based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two tables: `countdown` and `time_limit`

```
countdown:
    -------    ---------    ---------    -------
    cnt_id     tlimit_id    cnt_start    cnt_end
    -------    ---------    ---------    -------
    1          1            08:00:00     x
    2          3            09:00:00     y

time_limit
    ---------    ----------
    tlimit_id    tlimit_val
    ---------    ----------
    1            00:30:00
    2            01:00:00
    3            01:30:00
```

so x=08:30:00
and y=10:30:00

My question is this: is there a way that I could set up the database tables (without php scripting) so that the value of cnt_end is always (cnt_start) PLUS (tlimit_val) ?

Comment: you mean plus `tlimit_val`  You could use a view for this, or search 'mysql update with join' if you want to update x/y

Comment: Confirm whether you want to add cnt_start and tlimit_val or subtract as value of x and y are coming after summation as per your question.

Comment: @SidM GoatCo yes, i meant plus. apologies, i misspoke.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching values from database then you can use this query

```
select countdown.cnt_id,countdown.tlimit_id,countdown.cnt_start,(countdown.cnt_start+time_limit.tlimit_val) AS cnt_end from countdown INNER JOIN  time_limit on countdown.tlimit_id = time_limit.tlimit_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [`Goat CO`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130801/goat-co), you can create a view on top of `countdown` table to automatically insert a computed value in a `cnt_end` column.

```
CREATE VIEW magic_countdown AS
SELECT a.cnt_id, a.tlimit_id, a.cnt_start, a.cnt_start + b.tlimit_val AS cnt_end
FROM countdown a, time_limit b
WHERE a.tlimit_id = b.tlimit_id;
```

And use `magic_countdown` in your SQL statements to insert data instead of `countdown`

An alternative is to use a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername AFTER INSERT (or UPDATE)
ON countdown
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE countdown SET countdown.cnt_end=time_limit.tlimit_val+countdown.cnt_start WHERE countdown.tlimit_id = time_limit.tlimit_id
```

See [MySQL Documentation for Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)